# Breaking a program for a specific condition

Tags: c#, c, xcode

I am building a quadratic equation solver using c language and i want to stop the program if the user enters 0 as a value for a. How could i do that?

I have tried using break in switch syntax but it doesnt stop the program.

Comment: Kindly do not spam language tags. ```C#``` is not the same as ```C```, and shouldn't be used synonymously. Edit the question to include the code.

Comment: "i want to stop the program if..." You want the `stdlib.h` function: `exit();` Happy reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` keyword in a `switch-case` statement works merely leaves the switch itself, i suppose you are doing a loop of some kind?
This would be easier with code, but either way, in these cases, while it is also "correct" to use a `return` statement, it is more apt to declare a variable called a flag that controls the flow of the program:

```c
int main()
{
   int flag = 0;
   while (!flag && other_conditions)
   {
       // get value of a
       if (a == 0)
           flag = 1;
       else
       {
            // do the rest
       }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Were this in a function, it works in a very similar fashion in which you must, for example pass a flag by reference and check if that flag is 1 or 0.

```c
int func(args, int*x)
{
    if (a == 0)
         *x = 1;
    else
    {
        //code
    }
    return result;
}
```

After which in the main function you'd need to check if that value is 1 or 0 and go to the end of the program if it's 1 continue if it's not.

On an addendum, as some users have mentioned, you can indeed use returns and exit statements, however these are considered bad programming practices, at least for a language such as C that is **structured**, thus should at least attempt to follow the Single Entry Single Exit rule.

Answer (score 0):

In the main function of your C program just insert

```
return <something>
```

and return whatever you want. If you are calculating that from an other function you will have to insert the return statement in that function and again in the main function.
The break statement ends the loops.

It would probably help to see your actual code